# New monitor connected to HDMI adaptor doesn't show output after booting 

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Hello out there in the multiple monitors’ world.  I am a very old newbie in your world and need help.

I just purchased a new Asus VH236H monitor and hooked it up the HDMI port of an ATI Radeon HD4300 / 4500 Series display adaptor.  I left the old Princeton LCD19 (TMDS) hooked up to the DVI port of the same display adaptor.

Both monitors displayed the boot sequence, after I fired good old Sarastro2 (Asus P5Q Pro Turbo – Dual Core E5300 – 2.60 GHz) up.  The Asus lacked one half of a second behind the Princeton until the Windows 7 Ultimate SP 1 boot up was complete.  Then the Asus displayed “HDMI NO SIGNAL” and went into hibernation.  The Princeton stayed lit up as before.

Both monitors are displayed on the “Screen Resolution Setup Display” and I plaid around with them for a while. The only thing I accomplished was to shove the desktop icons from the Princeton to the still hibernating Asus.  The “Multiple displays:” is set to “Extend these displays”, the Orientation is “Landscape” and the Resolutions are set on both to the “recommended” one.  Both monitors show that they work properly in the advanced Properties display.

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing?

Never mind the opinions about the different resolutions of the two monitors.  I always can unhook the Princeton and give it to a Goodwill Store if I do not like the setup.  I just would like to make it work.

Any constructive help is very much appreciated, Thank you.

Thank you Anees Bakrain

Only the ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series adapter is displayed in the Device Manager, for that reason I have to assume that the onboard display adaptor is not active.

All 40 drivers of Sarastro2 are up to date and the HDMI cable can not be the problem because both monitors displayed the boot sequence up to the moment when Windows 7 was loaded completely.  This was the moment, when the Asus monitor lost its signal.

Both connectors, HDMI and DVI are connected and removing the DVI connector would not solve my problem of running both monitors simultaneously.

However, your suggestions shifted my seventy one year old brain into the next gear.  The only question remaining is; “Why the signals to the Asus monitor stop after the sequence is complete”.

The ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series adapter seems to be capable of sending simultaneous HDMI and DVI signals, what is done during the boot sequence.

Why do the signals change after the boot sequence is complete is the key question or der springende Punkt?  Is this a correct assumption slhck?

Answer (score -1):

First, Make sure to disable built in graphics card and try.
second,try to unplug DVI connector,plug HDMI connector,if there is no change then you maybe not installed the correct HDMI driver or you have to change HDMI cable.

Comment: Anees Bakrai, I still did not find out why the signals change after the boot sequence is complete.  However, the solution and therefore the correct answer to my problem is that it is a fact that the ATI Radeon HD 4300-4500 (at least the one installed in Sarastro2) does not send signals to a HDMI and DVI monitor simultaneously after the boot sequence is completed.  However it will send signals to either a HDMI or DVI, simultaneously with a monitor attached to VGA port.